# How to use P2D, P3D, FX2D with plain Java?

Tags: java, processing, noclassdeffounderror, renderer

I have only worked with [Processing's](https://processing.org/) standard renderer until now. I got a java project where i am working with processing included via maven.
Since other [renderers](https://processing.org/tutorials/rendering#:%7E:text=produce%20small%20editions.-,Processing,-has%20three%20primary) might be faster, i wanted to try using another for my current project, but any other renderer fails for me (P2D, P3D, FX2D). Only the default, Java2D works.

Seemed weird to me, so i started another project with nothing in it, just creating an empty frame. I first tried running it in the Processing.exe as a sketch, and it worked:

The Sketch code:

```
void setup()
{
  size(500, 200, P3D);
}

void draw()
{
}
```

I then rewrote it into plain java:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Test extends PApplet
{

        public void setup() {
        }

        public void draw() {
        }

        public void settings() {
                this.size(500, 200, P3D);
        }

        public static void main(final String[] passedArgs) {
                final String[] appletArgs = { "Test" };
                if (passedArgs != null) {
                        PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
                }
                else {
                        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
                }
        }
}
```

No matter what i tried so far, i keep running into the following exeption:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLException
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.createPGL(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:712)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.<init>(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:569)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphics3D.<init>(PGraphics3D.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2235)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2314)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10828)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10767)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10467)
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: com/jogamp/opengl/GLException
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2268)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2314)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10828)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10767)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10467)
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

I am working with Java 17, and already tried to run with Java 8 as i read this might work, but.. it didnt.
Is it not possible to run those P2D, P3D, FX2D sketches outside of the processing.exe?

Comment: I'd recommend using this Processing (4) maven distribution, which automatically includes all renderers (gl and javafx): https://github.com/micycle1/processing-core-4

Comment: I just found that github repo 2 days ago and used it! Its great, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even better solution to this problem would be to just use the newer processing4.
Micycle1 made the processing4-core usable with maven via JitPack: https://github.com/micycle1/processing-core-4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Adding following dependencies to the pom.xml solved it:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the application in the Processing IDE and just copy the exported files.

It also gives you an albeit poorly written .java file.

However, the files are different for every OS type so it can be annoying.

Using `P2D` does not necessarily save any CPU power or increase speed.

`FX2D` is faster but annoying.